# Write to RabbitMQ using Spark or Pig or Hive

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, apache-spark, rabbitmq, apache-pig

I some data in Amazon S3, produced on a daily basis, which i wanted to write to RabbitMQ (which i have not used before).

Is it possible to do this task in a distributed way using Spark or Pig or Hive?